# Missing library starting up QT5

Tags: linux, qt, shared-libraries, xcb

I have a Qt application that I am trying to run, but fails to start because it "could not  find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb".  When I run ldd on libqxcb.so all the libraries are linked except for one: `libxcb-icccm.so.1 => not found`

Now, I do have libxcb-icccm.so.4 on my machine, but if I create a symlink pointing to it, everything crashes and burns.  From everything I've found the icccm library comes from the XOrg libs, but when I download the source to build it, I have thus far ended up with libxcb-icccm.so.4 instead of libxcb-icccm.so.1

Am I doing something wrong, or am I just missing the version of the xcb libraries I need to build libxcb-icccm.so.1

Answer (score 1):

This version of the icccm library can be found in: [`xcb-util-0.3.6`](https://xcb.freedesktop.org/dist/)